# Controlling information flow and gating factor in Keras layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

Given a CNN architecture ([architecture image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGtu7.png)) where the information flow from one layer to another is controlled by a gating factor.
The fraction 'g' of information is sent to the immediate next layer and remaining '1-g' is sent to one of the forward layers (like a skip connection)

How to implement such an architecture in Keras?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the functional API Model.

For gates (automatic fraction g):

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import *

inputTensor = Input(someInputShape)

#the actual value
valueTensor = CreateSomeLayer(parameters)(inputTensor)

#the gate - this is the value of 'g', from zero to 1
gateTensor = AnotherLayer(matchingParameters, activation='sigmoid')(inputTensor)

#value * gate = fraction g
fractionG = Lambda(lambda x: x[0]*x[1])([valueTensor,gateTensor])

#value - fraction = 1 - g
complement = Lambda(lambda x: x[0] - x[1])([valueTensor,fractionG])

#each tensor may go into individual layers and follow individual paths:
immediateNextOutput = ImmediateNextLayer(params)(fractionG)
oneOfTheForwardOutputs = OneOfTheForwardLayers(params)(complement)

#keep going, make one or more outputs, and create your model:
model = Model(inputs=inputTensor, outputs=outputTensorOrListOfOutputTensors)
```

For giving two inputs to the same layer, concatenate, sum, multiply, etc., in order to make them one.

```
#concat
joinedTensor = Concatenate(axis=optionalAxis)([input1,input2])

#add
joinedTensor = Add()([input1,input2])

#etc.....

nextLayerOut = TheLayer(parameters)(joinedTensor)
```

#### If you want to control 'g' manually:

In this case, all we have to do is replace the `gateTensor` by a user defined one:

```
import keras.backend as K

gateTensor = Input(tensor=K.variable([g]))
```

Pass this tensor as an input when creating the model. (Since it's a `tensor` input, it won't change the way you use the `fit` methods).

```
model = Model(inputs=[inputTensor,gateTensor], outputs=outputTensorOrListOfOutputTensors)
```

Comment: Ah.... I though you'd let the model decide the fraction for itself....I'll create a version with manual fractioning.

Comment: Updated my answer. See at the end.

Comment: RuntimeError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor <tf.Variable 'Variable_4:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref> at layer "input_11". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: ['input_10', 'conv2d_10']

Comment: Ok, since the `gateTensor` is actually an input, it should go into the `Model` creation. See the updated answer.

Comment: That removed the error. But now the output shape has changed from (None,64,64,64) to (1,64,64,64). The first element of the output shape should be None to accept any number of images.

Comment: I can't help anymore if I don't see your code. PS: I updated the multiply layer with a `Lambda` layer, just in case.